# Object Oriented Design of Card Deck - how to make it flexible to have more cards in the future

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, object

Suppose we have a Object Oriented Design of a Deck of Cards as in [Programming Example: Card, Hand, Deck](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c5/s4.html).

Copying from the URL, here is the complete Card class.

> It is general enough to be highly reusable, so the work that went into designing, writing, and testing it pays off handsomely in the long run.

```
/**
 * An object of type Card represents a playing card from a
 * standard Poker deck, including Jokers.  The card has a suit, which
 * can be spades, hearts, diamonds, clubs, or joker.  A spade, heart,
 * diamond, or club has one of the 13 values: ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
 * 8, 9, 10, jack, queen, or king.  Note that "ace" is considered to be
 * the smallest value.  A joker can also have an associated value; 
 * this value can be anything and can be used to keep track of several
 * different jokers.
 */

public class Card {

   public final static int SPADES = 0;   // Codes for the 4 suits, plus Joker.
   public final static int HEARTS = 1;
   public final static int DIAMONDS = 2;
   public final static int CLUBS = 3;
   public final static int JOKER = 4;

   public final static int ACE = 1;      // Codes for the non-numeric cards.
   public final static int JACK = 11;    //   Cards 2 through 10 have their 
   public final static int QUEEN = 12;   //   numerical values for their codes.
   public final static int KING = 13;

   /**
    * This card's suit, one of the constants SPADES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS,
    * CLUBS, or JOKER.  The suit cannot be changed after the card is
    * constructed.
    */
   private final int suit; 

   /**
    * The card's value.  For a normal card, this is one of the values
    * 1 through 13, with 1 representing ACE.  For a JOKER, the value
    * can be anything.  The value cannot be changed after the card
    * is constructed.
    */
   private final int value;

   /**
    * Creates a Joker, with 1 as the associated value.  (Note that
    * "new Card()" is equivalent to "new Card(1,Card.JOKER)".)
    */
   public Card() {
      suit = JOKER;
      value = 1;
   }

   /**
    * Creates a card with a specified suit and value.
    * @param theValue the value of the new card.  For a regular card (non-joker),
    * the value must be in the range 1 through 13, with 1 representing an Ace.
    * You can use the constants Card.ACE, Card.JACK, Card.QUEEN, and Card.KING.  
    * For a Joker, the value can be anything.
    * @param theSuit the suit of the new card.  This must be one of the values
    * Card.SPADES, Card.HEARTS, Card.DIAMONDS, Card.CLUBS, or Card.JOKER.
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the parameter values are not in the
    * permissible ranges
    */
   public Card(int theValue, int theSuit) {
      if (theSuit != SPADES && theSuit != HEARTS && theSuit != DIAMONDS && 
            theSuit != CLUBS && theSuit != JOKER)
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal playing card suit");
      if (theSuit != JOKER && (theValue < 1 || theValue > 13))
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal playing card value");
      value = theValue;
      suit = theSuit;
   }

   /**
    * Returns the suit of this card.
    * @returns the suit, which is one of the constants Card.SPADES, 
    * Card.HEARTS, Card.DIAMONDS, Card.CLUBS, or Card.JOKER
    */
   public int getSuit() {
      return suit;
   }

   /**
    * Returns the value of this card.
    * @return the value, which is one of the numbers 1 through 13, inclusive for
    * a regular card, and which can be any value for a Joker.
    */
   public int getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   /**
    * Returns a String representation of the card's suit.
    * @return one of the strings "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"
    * or "Joker".
    */
   public String getSuitAsString() {
      switch ( suit ) {
      case SPADES:   return "Spades";
      case HEARTS:   return "Hearts";
      case DIAMONDS: return "Diamonds";
      case CLUBS:    return "Clubs";
      default:       return "Joker";
      }
   }

   /**
    * Returns a String representation of the card's value.
    * @return for a regular card, one of the strings "Ace", "2",
    * "3", ..., "10", "Jack", "Queen", or "King".  For a Joker, the 
    * string is always numerical.
    */
   public String getValueAsString() {
      if (suit == JOKER)
         return "" + value;
      else {
         switch ( value ) {
         case 1:   return "Ace";
         case 2:   return "2";
         case 3:   return "3";
         case 4:   return "4";
         case 5:   return "5";
         case 6:   return "6";
         case 7:   return "7";
         case 8:   return "8";
         case 9:   return "9";
         case 10:  return "10";
         case 11:  return "Jack";
         case 12:  return "Queen";
         default:  return "King";
         }
      }
   }

   /**
    * Returns a string representation of this card, including both
    * its suit and its value (except that for a Joker with value 1,
    * the return value is just "Joker").  Sample return values
    * are: "Queen of Hearts", "10 of Diamonds", "Ace of Spades",
    * "Joker", "Joker #2"
    */
   public String toString() {
      if (suit == JOKER) {
         if (value == 1)
            return "Joker";
         else
            return "Joker #" + value;
      }
      else
         return getValueAsString() + " of " + getSuitAsString();
   }


} // end class Card
```

Suppose I want to include two jokers in this design without disturbing the current classes , how to achieve that ?

Comment: Can you please include a sample that is [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Questions should not be dependant on external links. Is this homework? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Not a homework. trying to come up with a design where I can have deck of cards such that it can be extended to include new cards

Comment: @May13ank Thats fine (in my opinion if it was homework that would be fine too) but we need the actual question, in its entirety here (external links are fine **but** if the question is unanswerable without then then the question is not good. Remember the hope is that this Q&A will be long term useful; can you garantee that that link will always be there?

Comment: Why don't you just new up an additional Joker and add it to the `Deck` ?

Answer (score 1):

In the `Card` class, one of the constructors is `(value, suit)`.  The Joker is defined as one of the card suites.  You can specify any value you wish to keep track of the Jokers.

The default constructor of the `Card` class creates a Joker.

You can define any additional cards you wish by adding new `final static int` values to the suit and value.

Answer (score 0):

Joker should be a rank (which you call "value") not a suit. In standard decks, the two jokers are different, one being typically more colorful. These are often called "red" and "black" jokers, and some games treat them differently. So a joker should have a rank (say, 14) and one should be a black suit and one a red suit.

Otherwise your design is good. Take a look at [Representing playing cards in software](https://web.archive.org/web/20161021164438/http://etceterology.com/blog/2013/5/23/representing-playing-cards-in-software)